# Stats total count decreases on increasing the date range for prom counter

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a simple prom counter linked to stats visualization, with total as a reducer function. The total count however decreases when I increase the date range.

[image: 12 hour total]

[image: 24 hour total]

I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the "rate" function. Accordingly with the [Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate):

> rate()
>
> rate(v range-vector) calculates the per-second average rate of
> increase of the time series in the range vector.

Increasing your data range will not always increase your per-second average rate.

Change the "rate" function to the "increase" one.

For more details see Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase).

Comment: what's the proper way to calculate the total count in time range here?

Comment: I added more info to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the query to

```
increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count{uri="/api/otp.send", status="200", outcome="SUCCESS"}[$__interval])
```

The total count came out correctly.